# Email not popping up in Sharekit

Tags: iphone, sharekit

Inside the Sharekit 's SHK file, there's a function called `ShowViewController` which bring the `Mailcontroller` up.

In SHKMail

`[[SHK currentHelper] showViewController:mailController];`

In the SHK file

```
// Show the nav email controller
[topViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

vc is the viewcontroller of the Mail.

I checked both the `topviewController` and `vc` are valid, however, nothing show up when the email button of the sharekit is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried like this and it was working for me and hope it should work for you as well

```
-(UIViewController*)getRootViewController{

    return _APPDELEGATE.navigationController;
}

[[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:[self getRootViewController]];

[actionSheet showFromToolbar:_APPDELEGATE.navigationController.toolbar];
```

**I do not know why my above code is not working for you.**

Okay try this code, should work

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:someNSURL title:@"a title"];

//hack: force SHK to know the root view controller
[[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:self];

// Share the item
[SHKMail shareItem:item];

[item release];
```

Comment: Above looks like its trying to show the actionsheet. I don't have issue in displaying the actionsheet. For me the issue is clicking the email button on the actionsheet that has no effect.

Comment: are you trying to use share kit on multiple view ?

Comment: I guess my problem is solved. basically my another view using presentModalViewController/dismissmodalviewcontroller interfering with sharekit. basically I use addsubview/removefromsuperview instead. the issue now gone away.